# Check whether method body conains ViewResult returns

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm trying to fix this issue https://github.com/dotnet-security-guard/roslyn-security-guard/issues/60 Affected file is https://github.com/dotnet-security-guard/roslyn-security-guard/blob/master/RoslynSecurityGuard/Analyzers/CsrfTokenAnalyzer.cs

There is `DiagnosticAnalyzer` implemented and the logic in `VisitMethods(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext ctx)` method is not correct for API method. So that I want to add such check to that method to exclude all the controller methods which return `ViewResult` instance as API method will not return a view.

Can you suggest me how can I traverse a C# (and VB) method body and find if a body contains any statement which returns ViewResult instance?

Comment: @jeroen-vannevel is my question specific enough and have enough details now?

Answer (score 0):

Call [`.DescendantNodes()`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Syntax/SyntaxNode.cs,44fe5c9234642a23) on the method's node and filter for all `return` statements.

For each `return` statement you find, check whether `.Expression` (which may not exist)'s TypeSymbol (from the semantic model) is / is convertible to `ViewResult`.

To handle expression-bodied members, do the same check for `ArrowExpressionClause`.